# Can I use the word ちる when I want to say that ´the apples fell from the tree´?

Tags: meaning, verbs

It is usually used for leaves, blossoms

Answer (score 6):

No. 散る【ちる】 is used for leaves and blossoms, but *not* for fruits or branches. You have to say リンゴの実が**落ちる** instead.

> #### [散る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%95%A3%E3%82%8B_%28%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8B%29/)
>
> **花や葉が**、茎や枝から離れて落ちる。

Answer (score 4):

No, 散る tells that something breaks into pieces and scatters away, and that's why it can be used for petals and leaves, i.e. light parts of the plant that break off one by one and swirl down in the air.

An apple fruit only straightly goes down faithfully to gravity once drops, thus only can be depicted with 落ちる. I can only imagine something like a [touch-me-not fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impatiens) that could be suited for the word 散る.